# Netlify deployment failed with Next.js 12

Tags: next.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy my next.js app to netlify however I am getting netlify serverless function dependency error, I don't have access to any netlify serverless functions so I can't see why those functions are giving errors. I have search everywhere online and nobody seems to have gotten this error before.

In the first step plugin-nextjs my other next.js deployments use webpack 5 like this:

```
12:47:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:47:14 AM:   1. @netlify/plugin-nextjs (onPreBuild event)                  
12:47:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:47:14 AM: ​
12:47:14 AM: Using Next.js 11.1.2
12:47:14 AM: Warning: support for Next.js >=11.1.0 is experimental
12:47:14 AM: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
12:47:14 AM: The "target" config property must be one of "serverless", "experimental-serverless-trace". Building with "serverless" target.
12:47:15 AM: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
12:47:15 AM: Next.js cache restored.
12:47:15 AM: ​
12:47:15 AM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onPreBuild completed in 1.2s)
12:47:15 AM:
```

However this next.js deployment has no webpack 5. Why is this?

```
7:56:19 AM:   1. @netlify/plugin-nextjs (onPreBuild event)                  
7:56:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: Using Next.js 12.0.1
7:56:19 AM: Warning: support for Next.js >=11.1.0 is experimental
7:56:19 AM: The "target" config property must be one of "serverless", "experimental-serverless-trace". Building with "serverless" target.
7:56:19 AM: No Next.js cache to restore.
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onPreBuild completed in 544ms)
```

This is the error in the function dependency, It says it cannot find module webpack and I don't know how to fix this error. Why is there no webpack like my other deployments?

```
7:57:09 AM:   Error message
7:57:09 AM:   A Netlify Function failed to require one of its dependencies.
7:57:09 AM:   Please make sure it is present in the site's top-level "package.json".​
7:57:09 AM:   In file "/opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal/next_reviews_id/next_reviews_id.js"
7:57:09 AM:   Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

Full build log with NETLIFY_BUILD_DEBUG=true

```
7:56:08 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:08 AM:   Netlify Build                                                 
7:56:08 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Version
7:56:08 AM:   @netlify/build 20.0.4
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Flags
7:56:08 AM:   apiHost: api.netlify.com
7:56:08 AM:   baseRelDir: true
7:56:08 AM:   branch: master
7:56:08 AM:   buildId: 61aa21c6ec7b1a4480064e45
7:56:08 AM:   buildbotServerSocket: /tmp/netlify-buildbot-socket
7:56:08 AM:   cacheDir: /opt/build/cache
7:56:08 AM:   cachedConfigPath: /tmp/netlify_config.json
7:56:08 AM:   context: production
7:56:08 AM:   cwd: /opt/build/repo
7:56:08 AM:   deployId: 61aa21c6ec7b1a4480064e47
7:56:08 AM:   featureFlags:
7:56:08 AM:     - buildbot_build_go_functions
7:56:08 AM:   framework: next
7:56:08 AM:   functionsDistDir: /tmp/zisi-61aa21c6ec7b1a4480064e47
7:56:08 AM:   mode: buildbot
7:56:08 AM:   nodePath: /opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node
7:56:08 AM:   repositoryRoot: /opt/build/repo
7:56:08 AM:   saveConfig: true
7:56:08 AM:   sendStatus: true
7:56:08 AM:   siteId: 848233d9-2dea-4c7f-9a02-75e5c3261606
7:56:08 AM:   statsd:
7:56:08 AM:     host: datadog-agent
7:56:08 AM:     port: 8125
7:56:08 AM:   testOpts:
7:56:08 AM:     silentLingeringProcesses: ''
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Current directory
7:56:08 AM:   /opt/build/repo
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Config file
7:56:08 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Resolved config
7:56:08 AM:   build:
7:56:08 AM:     command: CI=FALSE npm run build
7:56:08 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
7:56:08 AM:     environment:
7:56:08 AM:       - NETLIFY_BUILD_DEBUG
7:56:08 AM:       - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
7:56:08 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/out
7:56:08 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
7:56:08 AM:   plugins:
7:56:08 AM:     - inputs: {}
7:56:08 AM:       origin: ui
7:56:08 AM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Context
7:56:08 AM:   production
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Available plugins
7:56:08 AM:    - @algolia/netlify-plugin-crawler@1.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - @bharathvaj/netlify-plugin-airbrake@1.0.2
7:56:08 AM:    - @helloample/netlify-plugin-replace@1.1.4
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-angular-universal@1.0.1
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-gatsby@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-lighthouse@2.1.2
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@3.9.2
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-sitemap@0.8.1
7:56:08 AM:    - @sentry/netlify-build-plugin@1.1.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-build-plugin-dareboost@1.2.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-build-plugin-debugbear@1.0.6
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-build-plugin-perfbeacon@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-build-plugin-speedcurve@2.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-deployment-hours-plugin@0.0.10
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-a11y@0.0.12
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-add-instagram@0.2.2
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-algolia-index@0.3.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-amp-server-side-rendering@1.0.2
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-brand-guardian@1.0.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-build-logger@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-cache-nextjs@1.4.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-cecil-cache@0.2.5
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-checklinks@4.1.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-chromium@1.1.4
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-contextual-env@0.3.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-cypress@2.2.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-debug-cache@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-encrypted-files@0.0.5
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-fetch-feeds@0.2.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache@0.3.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-get-env-vars@1.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-ghost-inspector@1.0.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-ghost-markdown@3.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-gmail@1.1.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-gridsome-cache@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-hashfiles@4.0.2
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-html-validate@1.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-hugo-cache-resources@0.2.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-image-optim@0.4.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-inline-critical-css@1.2.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-inline-functions-env@1.0.8
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-inline-source@1.0.4
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-is-website-vulnerable@1.0.10
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-jekyll-cache@1.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-js-obfuscator@1.0.20
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-minify-html@0.3.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-next-dynamic@1.0.9
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-nimbella@2.1.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-no-more-404@0.0.15
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-nx-skip-build@0.0.4
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-pagewatch@1.0.4
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-prerender-spa@1.0.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-prisma-provider@0.3.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-pushover@0.1.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-qawolf@1.2.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-rss@0.0.8
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-search-index@0.1.5
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-snyk@1.2.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-stepzen@1.0.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-subfont@6.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-submit-sitemap@0.2.3
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-to-all-events@1.3.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-use-env-in-runtime@1.2.1
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-visual-diff@2.0.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-plugin-webmentions@1.1.0
7:56:08 AM:    - netlify-purge-cloudflare-on-deploy@1.2.0
7:56:08 AM: ​
7:56:08 AM: ❯ Installing plugins
7:56:08 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@3.9.2
7:56:18 AM: ​
7:56:18 AM: ❯ Loading plugins
7:56:18 AM:    - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@3.9.2 from Netlify app (latest 3.9.2, expected 3.9.2, compatible 3.9.2)
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:19 AM:   1. @netlify/plugin-nextjs (onPreBuild event)                  
7:56:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: Using Next.js 12.0.1
7:56:19 AM: Warning: support for Next.js >=11.1.0 is experimental
7:56:19 AM: The "target" config property must be one of "serverless", "experimental-serverless-trace". Building with "serverless" target.
7:56:19 AM: No Next.js cache to restore.
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onPreBuild completed in 544ms)
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:19 AM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
7:56:19 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:56:19 AM: ​
7:56:19 AM: $ CI=FALSE npm run build
7:56:20 AM: > shoppingfirst@0.1.0 build
7:56:20 AM: > next build
7:56:20 AM: info  - Checking validity of types...
7:56:24 AM: ./components/ShopDetail/ShopDetail.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 14:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 61:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'IsTokenExpired'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 82:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initialize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 230:17  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: 239:17  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: ./components/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCart.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 21:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 75:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'IsTokenExpired'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 160:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initialize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 172:29  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: 276:29  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 354:25  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: ./components/error/error.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 14:25  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: 14:25  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
7:56:24 AM: 23:25  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: ./components/home/home.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 19:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 25:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 35:21  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: ./components/homepagenav.js
7:56:24 AM: 27:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initialize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 37:25  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 39:33  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: 46:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 53:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 60:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 62:41  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 67:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 74:33  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: ./components/login/login.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 129:25  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: 139:29  Warning: passHref is missing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
7:56:24 AM: ./components/profile/profile.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 12:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 72:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'IsTokenExpired'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 91:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initialize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: ./components/reviews/reviews.component.js
7:56:24 AM: 14:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'router'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 62:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'IsTokenExpired'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 266:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'item'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
7:56:24 AM: 312:29  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: 466:25  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
7:56:24 AM: info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
7:56:24 AM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
7:56:33 AM: (node:1686) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
7:56:33 AM: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
7:56:58 AM: (node:1686) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_HAS_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.hasEntryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
7:57:00 AM: info  - Compiled successfully
7:57:00 AM: info  - Collecting page data...
7:57:06 AM: info  - Generating static pages (0/10)
7:57:06 AM: info  - Generating static pages (2/10)
7:57:06 AM: info  - Generating static pages (4/10)
7:57:06 AM: info  - Generating static pages (7/10)
7:57:06 AM: info  - Generating static pages (10/10)
7:57:06 AM: info  - Finalizing page optimization...
7:57:06 AM: Page                                       Size     First Load JS
7:57:06 AM: ┌ ○ /                                      901 B          82.1 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/1f38b9496aad450b.css             714 B
7:57:06 AM: ├   /_app                                  0 B            71.5 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /404                                   194 B          71.7 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├ λ /api/hello                             0 B            71.5 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /contact                               1.76 kB          83 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/e27553073b9b95aa.css             799 B
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /error                                 687 B          81.9 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/584bcb5ea24d7758.css             470 B
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /login                                 1.61 kB        85.3 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/7b47e06b7095eb0d.css             913 B
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /profile (308 ms)                      4.72 kB         122 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/9108b6e04dbdc0ab.css             614 B
7:57:06 AM: ├ λ /reviews/[id]                          3.58 kB         118 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/6928b974908cb068.css             1.6 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /shopdetail                            2.73 kB         100 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/cde3d10604451cc4.css             1.27 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├ ○ /shoppingcart                          38.8 kB         136 kB
7:57:06 AM: ├   └ css/f0adb3181014ff82.css             2.53 kB
7:57:06 AM: └ ○ /signup                                3.89 kB         114 kB
7:57:06 AM:     └ css/4a9850401663f389.css             552 B
7:57:06 AM: + First Load JS shared by all              71.5 kB
7:57:06 AM:   ├ chunks/framework-0f8b31729833af61.js   42.4 kB
7:57:06 AM:   ├ chunks/main-a4a290bc70e8d102.js        27.8 kB
7:57:06 AM:   ├ chunks/pages/_app-fb7ecd67e368caea.js  492 B
7:57:06 AM:   ├ chunks/webpack-d652c94a67f1027e.js     784 B
7:57:06 AM:   └ css/40e3da143f12909c.css               742 B
7:57:06 AM: λ  (Lambda)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
7:57:06 AM: ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: (build.command completed in 47s)
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:06 AM:   3. @netlify/plugin-nextjs (onBuild event)                     
7:57:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: Detected Next.js site. Copying files...
7:57:06 AM: ** Running Next on Netlify package **
7:57:06 AM:  Next on Netlify 
7:57:06 AM: ️ Copying public folder to /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:06 AM:  Copying static NextJS assets to /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up API endpoints as Netlify Functions in /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up pages with getInitialProps as Netlify Functions in /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up pages with getServerSideProps as Netlify Functions in /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal
7:57:06 AM:  Copying pre-rendered pages with getStaticProps and JSON data to /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up pages with getStaticProps and fallback: true as Netlify Functions in /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up pages with getStaticProps and revalidation interval as Netlify Functions in /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal
7:57:06 AM:  Copying pre-rendered pages without props to /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:06 AM: Building 11 pages
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up redirects
7:57:06 AM:  Setting up headers
7:57:06 AM: ✅ Success! All done!
7:57:06 AM: Netlify configuration property "functions.*.included_files" value changed to [
7:57:06 AM:   '!node_modules/@next/swc-*/**/*',
7:57:06 AM:   '!node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer/**/*'
7:57:06 AM: ].
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: ❯ Updated config
7:57:06 AM:   build:
7:57:06 AM:     command: CI=FALSE npm run build
7:57:06 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
7:57:06 AM:     environment:
7:57:06 AM:       - NETLIFY_BUILD_DEBUG
7:57:06 AM:       - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
7:57:06 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:06 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
7:57:06 AM:   functions:
7:57:06 AM:     '*':
7:57:06 AM:       included_files:
7:57:06 AM:         - '!node_modules/@next/swc-*/**/*'
7:57:06 AM:         - '!node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer/**/*'
7:57:06 AM:   headers:
7:57:06 AM:     - for: /_next/static/chunks/*      values:        cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable  plugins:    - inputs: {}      origin: ui      package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'  redirects:    - from: /api/hello      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_api_hello    - from: /_next/data/xQ9hR1q8t1P0nmOYcCzDn/reviews/:id.json      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_reviews_id    - force: true      from: /_next/image*      query:        q: ':quality'        url: ':url'        w: ':width'      status: 301      to: /nextimg/:url/:width/:quality    - from: /nextimg/*      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_image    - from: /reviews/:id      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_reviews_id​
7:57:06 AM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onBuild completed in 130ms)
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:06 AM:   4. Functions bundling                                         
7:57:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:06 AM: Packaging Functions from .netlify/functions-internal directory:
7:57:06 AM:  - next_api_hello/next_api_hello.js
7:57:06 AM:  - next_image/next_image.js
7:57:06 AM:  - next_reviews_id/next_reviews_id.js
7:57:06 AM: ​
7:57:09 AM: ​
7:57:09 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:09 AM:   Dependencies installation error                               
7:57:09 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:57:09 AM: ​
7:57:09 AM:   Error message
7:57:09 AM:   A Netlify Function failed to require one of its dependencies.
7:57:09 AM:   Please make sure it is present in the site's top-level "package.json".​
7:57:09 AM:   In file "/opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal/next_reviews_id/next_reviews_id.js"
7:57:09 AM:   Cannot find module 'webpack'
7:57:09 AM:   Require stack:
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/bundlers/zisi/resolve.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/bundlers/zisi/traverse.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/bundlers/esbuild/src_files.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/bundlers/esbuild/index.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/bundlers/index.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/node/index.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/runtimes/index.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it/dist/main.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/plugins_core/functions/index.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/steps/get.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/core/main.js
7:57:09 AM:   - /opt/buildhome/node-deps/node_modules/@netlify/build/src/core/bin.js
7:57:09 AM: ​
7:57:09 AM:   Resolved config
7:57:09 AM:   build:
7:57:09 AM:     command: CI=FALSE npm run build
7:57:09 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
7:57:09 AM:     environment:
7:57:09 AM:       - NETLIFY_BUILD_DEBUG
7:57:09 AM:       - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
7:57:09 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/out
7:57:09 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
7:57:09 AM:   functions:
7:57:09 AM:     '*':
7:57:09 AM:       included_files:
7:57:09 AM:         - '!node_modules/@next/swc-*/**/*'
7:57:09 AM:         - '!node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer/**/*'
7:57:09 AM:   headers:
7:57:11 AM:     - for: /_next/static/chunks/*      values:        cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable  plugins:    - inputs: {}      origin: ui      package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'  redirects:    - from: /api/hello      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_api_hello    - from: /_next/data/xQ9hR1q8t1P0nmOYcCzDn/reviews/:id.json      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_reviews_id    - force: true      from: /_next/image*      query:        q: ':quality'        url: ':url'        w: ':width'      status: 301      to: /nextimg/:url/:width/:quality    - from: /nextimg/*      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_image    - from: /reviews/:id      status: 200      to: /.netlify/functions/next_reviews_idCaching artifacts
7:57:11 AM: Started saving node modules
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving node modules
7:57:11 AM: Started saving build plugins
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving build plugins
7:57:11 AM: Started saving pip cache
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving pip cache
7:57:11 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
7:57:11 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
7:57:12 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
7:57:12 AM: Started saving go dependencies
7:57:12 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
7:57:14 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
7:57:14 AM: Creating deploy upload records
7:57:14 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
7:57:14 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
7:57:14 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m54.071695894s
```

Comment: it seems like next 12 is the issue, when I downgrade to next 11.1.2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your project to netlify, `@netlify/plugin-nextjs` gets installed automatically. If you [read the docs](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-nextjs)

> The serverless and experimental-serverless-trace targets are
> deprecated in Next 12, and all builds with this plugin will now use
> the default server target. If you previously set the target in your
> next.config.js, you should remove it.

in `next.config.js`, remove

```
 target:"serverless"
```

Comment: Next.js is on major version 13 now and Netlify support of Next versions >11.1.0 are still listed as experimental.  For me, Netlify is failing on configs that it installs itself without apparent access to them in the Netlify UI.